# MatLab: Error with plotting 1/x

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to use fplot() to plot 1/x:

`fplot(@(x) 1/x)`

However, when I do this, I get an error message:

> Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output
>   with the same size and shape as the input arguments.

How can I plot 1/x without this error?

Answer (score 2):

The warning is telling you that the input to the function could be any arbitrarily-sized array, and you need to write your [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to accommodate that. This means you need to use the element-wise [right-array division operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html) `./` instead of the [right-matrix division operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/mrdivide.html) `/`. This should do away with the warning messages:

```
fplot(@(x) 1./x);
```